# Can you use paypal payment with Bitcoins?

Tags: alternatives, payment, paypal

Many stores offer PayPal as payment method.

Is it possible to use Bitcoins to pay in these stores somehow without having a PayPal account yourself?

Comment: Paypal said they will never support Bitcoins or Crypto "Never say never..." So not sure what you asking but No. Bitcoins works differently. You need a store that accepts Bitcoins and you need a wallet and a way to send the coins to the stores address.

Comment: This is incorrect. Two very high up people in Paypal have said they are looking into possibilities the Bitcoin has to offer within their business.

Comment: I thought more like something like Bitspend.net was, that was a site with the intention of providing the Bitcoin community a way to purchase anything they wanted, from any website, and pay with Bitcoins. But that is closed down now

Answer (score 0):

http://www.proxycoins.com/ might be relevant, it's a market for having people buy on your behalf, where you pay them with Bitcoin.